# Доступ к полям через свойства

Tags: ооп, delphi-7, delphi, объекты, классы

Я прочитал в книге Хомоненко, Гофмана, Мещерякова "Delphi 7. Наиболее полное руководство" следующую вещь:
Ключевые слова read и write являются зарезервированными внутри объявления свойства и служат для указания методов класса, с помощью которых выполняется чтение значение поля, связанного со свойством, или запись нового значения в это поле.
Так ли это?
Далее приводится пример:

```
type TNewClass=class(TObject)
  private
    FCode: integer;
    FSign: char;
    FNote: string;
  published
    property Code: integer read FCode write FCode;
    property Sign: char read FSign write FSign;
    propery Note: string read FNote write FNote;
end;
```

После зарезервированных слов read и write указаны имена полей, а как же указываются методы, осуществляющие чтение и запись полей? Или же геттеры и сеттеры имеют одноименное название с полем, но такого же не может быть?

Comment: Вместо read FCode  используй Read GetFCode и соответственно write SetFCode

напиши
property Code: integer read GetFCode write SetFCode;

и нажми Ctrl+C
редактор кода создаст заготовки процедур и функций, а переменную FCode: integer; вообще можешь убрать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указание поля после слова read и write означает, что доступ к приватным полям может осуществляться через соответствующие свойства, т. е. ObjectNewClass.Code и никакой реализации геттеров и сеттеров в таком случае не надо.

Answer (score 2):

```
property FCode: Integer read getCode write setCode;
function TNewClass.setCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := FCode;
end;

procedure TNewClass.getCode(const Value: Integer);
begin
  FCode := Value;
end;
```

Как раз конструкцией read и write вы указываете методы, которые являются по сути геттерами и сеттерами полей. И не забывайте определить их

```
procedure FCode(const Value: Integer);
function FCode: Integer;
```

Comment: @stck, т. е. правильно ли я понял, что геттеры и сеттеры одноименны с названиями соответствующих полей (ведь в таком случае если в классе есть и геттер, и сеттер для какого-нибудь поля, то они будут иметь одинаковое имя, совпадающее с именем поля)?

Comment: @ivan31, нет. Вы можете называть как хотите - пример подправил:)

Comment: @stck, а что же имелось ввиду в книге Хомоненко, Гофмана, Мещерякова - ведь там же название геттеров и сеттеров совпадают с названиями соответствующих полей?

Comment: @ivan31, имелось ввиду метод установки. Есть косвенный(через метод-посредник, как указал я) и есть прямой, т.е. когда осуществляется доступ к полю через свойство

Comment: @stck , что значит метод установки - это сеттер? Так он указывается после слово write, но тогда в примере в книге указан прямой метод - сеттер, который является одноименным с геттером (после слова read, что уже мне не нравится, хотя у них разная сигнатура, т. е. в принципе можно отличить) и является одноименным с самим полем (что также мне не нравится)?
Или указание поля после слова read и write означает, что доступ к приватным полям может осуществляться через соответствующие свойства, т. е. ObjectNewClass.Code  и никакой реализации геттеров и сеттеров в таком случае не надо?

Comment: @ivan31 вы правильно поняли. сокращенная запись позволяет не писать геттеры и сеттеры. Но если в какой-то момент вам захочется дописать обработку просто поменяете ``write FCode`` на ``write SetCode``. 

N.B. Есть замечательная функция Ctrl-Shift-C (complete class at cursor) метод и его имплементация автоматом добавятся.

Comment: @stck у вас получилось, что и свойство и геттеры и сеттеры и поле называются одинаково FCode, так не получится: Identifier redeclared.

Comment: Подразумевалась перегрузка

Comment: 1. нет overload
2. геттеры и сеттеры не могут быть перегружены
3. переменные перегружать методами тоже нельзя